# como descargar toda la información de una tabla paginada con función javascript

Tags: javascript, datatables

Actualmente estoy creando una tabla con varios tr dentro del thead, esta tabla la estoy armando con datatable, al momento de descargar a excel con la opción que me da el datatable, este no me descarga todos los tr del thead solo me descarga el último, he leído que se puede modificar el datatools, lo cual ya he realizado pero no funciona. lo otro es que leí que el datatable no lo soporta. Para poder solucionar mi tema de la cabecera, ocupe una función en javascript si bien descarga todo los tr del thead, no me trae toda la información, es decir, que solo descarga las filas que se encuentran en la vista y no las que están paginadas.
cualquier solución me para las dos opciones me sirve, que el datatable muestre todo el thead o en la función de js me traiga lo paginado.

```
var tableToExcel = (function() {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
        template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
    xmlns: x = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
    xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" > < meta http - equiv = "content-type"
    content = "application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8" > '

        +
        '<head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>' +
        '<x:ExcelWorkbook>' +
        '<x:ExcelWorksheets>' +
        '<x:ExcelWorksheet>' +
        '<x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name>' +
        '<x:WorksheetOptions>' +
        '<x:DisplayGridlines/>' +
        '</x:WorksheetOptions>' +
        '<ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>' +
        '<ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>' +
        '</x:ExcelWorksheet>' +

        // + '<Header x:Data="&amp;CTHIS IS THE HEADER (CENTER)"/>'
        'Footer x:Data="&amp;RTHIS IS THE FOOTER (RIGHT)"/>' +
        // + '<Layout x:Orientation="Landscape" x:CenterHorizontal="1"/>'


        '</x:ExcelWorksheets>' +
        '</x:ExcelWorkbook>' +
        '</xml>' +
        '<![endif]-->' +
        '</head>' +
        '<body>' +
        '<table border=1>{table}</table>' +
        '</body>' +
        '</html>',
        base64 = function(s) {
            return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
        },
        format = function(s, c) {
            return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) {
                return c[p];
            })
        }
    return function(table, name) {
        if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
        var ctx = {
            worksheet: name || 'Worksheet',
            table: table.innerHTML
        }
        window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
    }
})();
```

Comment: Es un poco densa tu explicación, pero me he quedado con un detalle que me chirría mucho: la especificación HTML dice expresamente que una tabla (`<table>`) [sólo puede tener un elemento `<thead`> como máximo](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/tabular-data.html#the-thead-element). Es normal que datatables no te lo admita.

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar qué quieres conseguir con múltiples theads? Quizá sea más sencillo buscar otro enfoque.

Comment: necesito exportar la tabla completa, que ello incluye todo el thead

Comment: @PabloLozano la tabla tiene un solo thead lo que en ella tiene son varios tr 3 en este caso, voy a editar la pregunta

Comment: no te muestra las filas "paginadas" porque no existen, dicho de otra forma, la información de la tabla te la guarda en objetos\arreglos y se secciona la información para escribir en el DOM solamente la que quieres ver, es decir, la información que esta paginada en realidad no está en el DOM